# Inserting from another table with matching value pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
     Table_One                                            Table_Two

ID ----- | ----- P_Name                              ID ----- | ----- P_Name
1X2      |  Name1                                             | Name1
1X3      |  Name2                                             | Name2
```

I want insert the ID into Table_Two where the ID matches on Table_One. For example The ID for Name2 on Table_2 needs to be 1X3

This is what I have so far and I'm getting errors. I'm pretty new to SQL. Be Gentle.

Oh I"m also using PostgreSQL .

```
insert into table_two (ID)
select "ID" from Table_One
where Table_One.P_Name = Table_Two.P_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *update* the table, not *insert*.  `Update` changes values in *columns*.  `Insert` adds new rows.  So:

```
update table_two t2
    set id = t1.id
    from table_one t1
    where t1.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: Wow thank you for that. It makes sense  now. Much appreciated.